# Can OpenCL build program from .cl source code together with a pre-built binary kernel?

Tags: opencl

My program has several kernels. I'd like to use offline compiler to compile one kernel into binary. So how can I build my program using other kernels and that one pre-built kernel binary?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to compile your other kernels using `clCreateProgramWithSource` and `clCompileProgram` and load your pre-built kernel with `clCreateProgramWithBinary`. Then you can link these programs using `clLinkProgram` to link both of the programs into one new program containing all kernels.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not possible or very complicated.

Kernels suppose to be small and modular. Composite kernels is bad practice.

What u can try is Enqueue kernels built from source together with kernels loaded as binary(with/out CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE f.e, with/out blocking or not flag). This way they will run in parallel.

What is left interkernel communication. You can try following:

1. Simple way: blocking run of kernel A after finishing start from host kernel B.
2. Complicated way:  using `clEnqueueMarkerWithWaitList, clEnqueueBarrierWithWaitList, clEnqueueMarker, clEnqueueWaitLIst, clWaitForEvents, clCreateUserEventclEnqueueBarrier`
3. `Pipes`. You can use pipes for it. clCreatePipe  I never tried. (OpenCL 2.0)